# Predictable graph of a random set

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stopping-times, filtrations

Assume that we work on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ equipped with a filtration $\mathcal{F}_t, t\ge 0$ and stochastic basis $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}, \mathbf{F})$ satisfies usual conditions.

Let $Z$ be a positive random variable and suppose its graph $[Z]$ is a predictable set. How to show that $Z$ is predictable  time?

By predictable section theorem there exists predictable  time $T_n$ such that $\mathbb{P}(T_n=\infty, Z<\infty)\le \frac{1}{2^n}$. If instead of $T_n$ we consider $S_n=T_1\wedge T_2\wedge\ldots\wedge T_n$, $S_n$ will be a decreasing sequence of stopping times. One can easily show that 
$$
\mathbb{P}(S_n=\infty, Z<\infty)=\mathbb{P}(T_1\wedge T_2\wedge\ldots\wedge T_n=\infty, Z<\infty)=
$$
$$
=\mathbb{P}\left(\{T_1=\infty, Z<\infty\}\cap \ldots \cap\{T_n=\infty, Z<\infty\}\right)\le 
\mathbb{P}\left(T_n=\infty, Z<\infty\right)\le \frac{1}{2^n}
$$
And defining $S(\omega)=\lim_n S_n(\omega)$ we conclude that 
$$
\mathbb P(S=\infty, Z<\infty)=0
$$
If we could show that

(1) the decreasing sequence of predictable  times $S_n$ has a certain property: for every $\omega$ there exists $n(\omega)$ (depending on $\omega$) such that $S(\omega)=S_{n(\omega)}(\omega)$ (or, equivalently, for every $\omega$ there exists $n(\omega)$ such that $S_n(\omega)=S_{n(\omega)}(\omega)$ for all $n\ge n(\omega)$)

(2) $S=Z$ a.s.

then by (1) $S$ would be a predictable time and by (2) $Z$ must also be a predictable time.

I suspect that the relationship $S=Z$ a.s. must directly follow from $\mathbb P(S=\infty, Z<\infty)=0$, however I failed to derive it.

Answer (score 1):

(1) follows from Borel-Cantelli because $\sum_n2^{-n}<\infty$. And (2) follows because $\{T_n<\infty\}\subset\{T_n=Z\}$, so *a fortiori* $\{S<\infty\}\subset\{S=Z\}$.